# Custom webpack for Angular 12 to include 'postcss-rtlcss' plugin

Tags: angular, webpack, plugins, saas, postcss

I am trying to install ***[postcss-rtlcss](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-rtlcss)*** library to support RTL styles in my Angular 12 app. The app has styles written in SCSS which is later compiled and minified to CSS. I have a custom webpack written for adding the postcss-rtlcss plugin in the rules:

```
module.exports = (config, options) => {
    addRtlConfig = (config) => {
        return {
            ...config, *//has all the existing default configs*
            module: {
                ...config.module,
                rules: [
                    ...config.module.rules,
                    {
                    test: /\.scss$|\.sass$/,
                      use: [
                        'style-loader',
                        'css-loader',
                        {
                          'loader': 'postcss-loader',
                          'options': {
                            postcssOptions: {
                                plugins: () => [require('postcss-rtlcss')({})],
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        'sass-loader'
                      ]
                    },
                  ]
                }
            }
        }
    return addRtlConfig(config);
}
```

But I am getting Error:

**Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js): SassError: Invalid CSS after "i": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was 'import api from "!.'
on line 1 of src/app/... from sass-loader/dist/cjs.js file**

Has anyone faced something similar?